# More than one Admin in sach:flow-db-admin package

Tags: meteor, admin

Is it possible to add more than one admin using **sach:flow-db-admin** Meteor package? If yes, a help would be great.

I already added two roles: user and admin but, when I add to the new user admin role it says: "You must be admin to see this page."

I have this code on the Startup function:

```
    if (Meteor.users.findOne("sxzdSFkeazB2sBs45"))
        Roles.addUsersToRoles("sxzdSFkeazB2sBs45", ['Admin']);


    if(!Meteor.roles.findOne({name: "User"}))
        Roles.createRole("User");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/sachinbhutani/flow-db-admin/tree/master/lib), you need a lowercase A in admin:

```
if (Meteor.users.findOne("sxzdSFkeazB2sBs45"))
    Roles.addUsersToRoles("sxzdSFkeazB2sBs45", ['admin']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed to 'Admin' to 'admin' (thanks to **Stephen Woods**) in the routes.js:

Accounts.onLogin(function(){

```
if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])){
    FlowRouter.go('Dashboard');
}

else if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['user']))  {
    FlowRouter.go('Account');
}
```

});

And now it's working, finally!